# Rails 3 render_component can't handle 304? / Force ActionDispatch::Request to avoid cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-304

I use render_component, https://github.com/vhochstein/render_component in Rails 3.

When my controller returns 304 result, the render_component fails with this error:

```
undefined method `redirect_url' for []:Array
```

on this line:

```
response = component_response(options, true)[2]

** if response.redirect_url **
  redirect_to response.redirect_url
else
  render :text => response.body, :status => response.status
end
```

The reason is because `controller.dispatch(action, request)` (result of `component_response`) returns an array with:

```
[304, {"ETag"=>"....", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"}, []]
```

instead of the 200 result which looks like:

```
[200, {"Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8", "ETag"=>"\"...\"", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate }, #<ActionDispatch::Response:0x007f8eee1918b8 @writer=...
```

Tried to add `request_env["Cache-Control"] = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"` as a header to the `ActionDispatch::Request` but no luck. I checked the header is received by the controller.

Comment: Do you really need components? Because 99% of the times components are a bad idea. It seems to me like you could use a shared response view just as easily in this case.